# Jasmine spec runner unit test results flash then disappear

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I have this file to run my unit tests:

unit-tests.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>Vepo Unit Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- #1. add the system.js and angular libraries -->
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>


  <script>
    // #2. Import the spec files explicitly
    Promise.all([
      System.import('js/app/landing-page/landing-page.component.spec.js'),
      System.import('js/app/pipes/my-uppercase.pipe.spec.js')
    ])

      // #3. wait for all imports to load ...
      //     then re-execute `window.onload` which
      //     triggers the Jasmine test-runner start
      //     or explain what went wrong.
      .then(window.onload)
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

When I start the server with npm start, then browse to localhost:3000/unit-tests.html in a web browser, it flashes with the green words of the two unit tests (as in the tests passed) and then the results just disappear.

It doesn't say no unit tests found, once it disappears. It just has this:

[image]

There are no console errors.

**EDIT: making it wait 9 seconds before reload:**

```
  <script>
    Promise.all([
      System.import('js/app/landing-page/landing-page.component.spec'),
      System.import('js/app/pipes/my-uppercase.pipe.spec')
    ]).then(setTimeout(window.onload, 9000)).catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
```

Makes the test results show for 9 seconds then disappear

However the answer is not to remove the promise and just import the test scripts straight away, because then the scripts are not found if they are bigger tests than a few lines of code.

The problem is that when the window reloads, it makes everything disappear. but without the reload, it doesn't find big unit tests. It finds tiny ones.

How do I stop the test results from disappearing on the reloading of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably we have got some race condition that can be solved by **asynchronous** `boot.js` file loading

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>Vepo Unit Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    System.import('node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js')
      .then(function() {
        return Promise.all([
          System.import('./spec/first.spec.js'),
          System.import('./spec/second.spec.js')
        ])
      })
      .then(function() {window.onload()})
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

### Looks promising:

[image]

Comment: It doesn't seem to make it work unfortunately. My console doesn't say anything. Not XHR GETS

Comment: Are you running it over local web server? Try to solve problems with XHR requests as this is basic needed functionality

Comment: I don't have any errors in the console, so is it still probably an XHR request issue? This is blocking me again as my solution below has stopped working. It does seem to be an issue with the promise not working.

Comment: Seems to be working now actually although it is displaying one of the test files results 3 times. Bit hard to put an answer on this question as it's just been lots of trial and error of configuration settings and I'm not sure what made it work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this works...it's not really an answer, it's just a workaround.

When I run "npm test" in the terminal, it opens the unit-tests.html and they run properly, the results stay on the screen.

I was going for the most basic setup, and I think the way it is working is less basic but probably better.